# How to update Db from passed in entity object

Tags: entity-framework, savechanges

I have a list of OrderDetail records that I have added, updated and deleted items from. I need to be able to pass this entity object to another layer for saving changes.

How can I do this? Do I need to detach the list from it's current Context before passing it to the next layer? Then Attach it to that layer's Context?

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the layer the object is passed into, you would indicate that the object is modified

```
 context.Entry(YourOrderDetailObject).State = EntityState.Modified;
 context.SaveChanges();
```